# Why do I get a timeout error if I send an AJAX POST request to my backend (only on other computers than my local machine)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, httprequest

If I send an AJAX POST request to my backend on another computer than my local computer the server is running on, I get a timeout error (I'm still in the same network).

```
const DOMAIN = 'http://10.0.0.14';

$.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      url: DOMAIN + ':3000',
      data: { mag: 'ok' },
      cache: false,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      timeout: 2000,
      async: true,
      success: function(data) {
          alert(data);
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert(jqXHR.toString());
          alert(textStatus);
          alert(errorThrown);
      } 
  });
```

(NOTE: if the timeout is more than 2 seconds it doesn't work too)

I've tried other API services and it works, but my API doesn't. So, is this rather a programming or a network error?

Comment: Well, you're setting the timeout to 2 seconds. Default is 30 I believe. Also, what service is running on 10.0.0.14?

Comment: This is a networking related issue not programming. The URL is a local IP address, you can't access that address on a different network.

Comment: @marekful what? You can access any 10.* address from any machine on the same local network with the appropriate subnet mask set. This is most certainly a regular old web programming question.

Comment: Have you confirmed that `http://10.0.0.14:3000` actually works? (e.g. have you tried it in its own tab, instead of as a jQuery ajax request?) Also, _don't ever use `alert()`_, use `console.log`, it's been the infinitely better debugging solution built into JS since 2010.

Comment: Yes => I get 'test' (statusCode: 200) back

Comment: now, I've tried it using another API service and it works properly, but my API still doesn't work